# Build a simple HTTP server in C

Tags: c, httpserver

I need to build a simple HTTP server in C. Any guidance? Links? Samples?

Comment: I got the same question and somehow I got incomplete but very simple implementation(incomplete) using C, which compiles under Ubuntu linux thought it would be valuable if I tag it here, https://blog.abhi.host/blog/2010/04/15/very-simple-http-server-writen-in-c/

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [tiny httpd](http://tinyhttpd.sourceforge.net/).  If you want to write it from scratch, then you'll want to *thoroughly* read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).  Use [BSD sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) to access the network at a really low level.

Comment: Or use inetd and skip the networking part.

Comment: Don't read [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) now, it obsoleted by: [RFC 7230](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230), 
[RFC 7231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231), 
[RFC 7232](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232), 
[RFC 7233](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233), 
[RFC 7234](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234), 
[RFC 7235](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235)

Comment: `tiny httpd` is also on github here:   https://github.com/larryhe/tinyhttpd

Answer (score 141):

I'd recommend that you take a look at: [A Practical Guide to Writing Clients and Servers](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http)

What you have to implement in incremental steps is:

1. Get your basic TCP sockets layer running (listen on port/ports, accept client connections and send/receive data).
2. Implement a buffered reader so that you can read requests one line (delimited by CRLF) at a time.
3. Read the very first line. Parse out the method, the request version and the path.
4. Implement header parsing for the "Header: value" syntax. Don't forget unfolding folded headers.
5. Check the request method, content type and content size to determine how/if the body will be read.
6. Implement decoding of content based on content type.
7. If you're going to support HTTP 1.1, implement things like "100 Continue", keep-alive, chunked transfer.
8. Add robustness/security measures like detecting incomplete requests, limiting max number of clients etc.
9. Shrink wrap your code and open-source it :)

Comment: Point #9, especially after posting a question here, +1 :)

Comment: Thank you for providing concepts rather than prebuilt solutions or links to RFC and Sockets. Reading the RFC and learning about Sockets isn't enough to build your own web server if you don't have these concepts in mind.

Comment: Reading requests line by line using "*a buffered reader*" (hence storing the line in a buffer until we find a CRLF), makes me anxoius about attacks that send gigabytes of data without CRLF. For this, I usually read using 'states', re-allocate the buffers on the go with the data, check for limits every read and send 414 appropriately. Except point #2, I agree with all the other points.

Answer (score 39):

An HTTP server is conceptually simple:

- Open port 80 for listening
- When contact is made, gather a little information (get mainly - you can ignore the rest for now)
- Translate the request into a file request
- Open the file and spit it back at the client

It gets more difficult depending on how much of HTTP you want to support  - POST is a little more complicated, scripts, handling multiple requests, etc.

But the base is very simple.

Comment: Thank you for providing concepts rather than prebuilt solutions or links to RFC and Sockets. Reading the RFC and learning about Sockets isn't enough to build your own web server if you don't have these concepts in mind.

Answer (score 30):

[Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose) (Formerly Simple HTTP Daemon) is pretty good. In particular, it's embeddable and compiles under Windows, Windows CE, and UNIX.

Answer (score 13):

Open a TCP socket on port 80, start listening for new connections, implement [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).
Depending on your purposes, you can ignore almost everything. At the easiest, you can send the same response for every request, which just involves writing text to the socket.

Answer (score 12):

Look at nweb (Nigel's Web Server), "a tiny, safe web server [...] with only 200 lines of C source code":

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3msld7qnNOhN1NXaFIwSFU2Mjg/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-ngY0neP78dxJKlFv0PJoDQ
<strike>http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/</strike>

The article includes pseudocode, explanations, and comments.

EDIT: IBM's link has died. I have saved a PDF of the webpage to Google Drive. Here is the code download:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3msld7qnNOhSGZGdDJJMmY0VHM/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-xkbf4mv0gN1sZrhBjt86UQ

@[ankushagarwal](https://github.com/ankushagarwal) has made a few changes and uploaded his version on GitHub:
https://github.com/ankushagarwal/nweb

Comment: Eh up voted without checking link :/ I'm looking for the exact thing you mentioned, if you find something can you ping me? Txt

Comment: @samayo IBM's link has died. I have provided some mirrors.

Comment: Here's a mirror by archive.org - which will hopefully be around for years to come: https://web.archive.org/web/20140905115151/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/

Answer (score 5):

I have written my own that you can use.  This one works has sqlite, is thread safe and is in C++ for UNIX.

You should be able to pick it apart and use the C compatible code.

http://code.google.com/p/mountain-cms/

Answer (score 5):

The [HTTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) were very useful for me when I had to do it for *my* homework.

Good luck with yours. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest looking at the source to something like [lighthttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.manning.com/hethmon/ -- "Illustrated Guide to HTTP by Paul S. Hethmon" from Manning is a very good book to learn HTTP protocol and will be very useful to someone implementing it /extending it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [duplicate with more responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library).

One candidate not mentioned yet is [spserver](http://code.google.com/p/spserver/).

Answer (score 1):

Use platform specific socket functions to encapsulate the HTTP protocol, just like guys behind [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) did.

Comment: But... Apache Server is the complete opposite of "simple"?